# google pagespeed test to slow

Tags: pagespeed

My magento 2 website performs well on `pingdom and gtmetrix`, but the performance on `google pagespeed` is very poor. How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pingdom and Gmetrix are doing desktop only tests. Pagespeed screenshot is showing Mobile test result. Mobile vs Desktop results are different.

Comment: YES. The PC score is 47

Comment: Mobile score has a different requirement to Desktop score. I recommend running Right Click -> Inspect -> Lighthouse -> Generate Report to see where there issue is. Here is a quick rundown how to use it to improve load times: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/lighthouse

I did notice the scores definitely have changed - I optimized my score in october to 64%, but now its only 30%. So something has changed in their tool. Start with Lighthouse and keep working.

Comment: thanks, i will check it

Comment: Enable magento profiler and check if which profiler takes long time
check if any loops are repetitive
reduce no of http request.
Remove all inline javascripts and css and create one js file or once css file so that when we merge css and js it will take only one http request
Enable production mode in magento 2 using php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production.
run compilation and check if any errors using this command php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Check if all caches are enabled if not run this command php bin/magento cache:enable

Answer (score 3):

- Enable magento profiler and check if which profiler takes long time
- check if any loops are repetitive
- reduce no of http request.
- Remove all inline javascripts and css and create one js file or once css file so that when we merge css and js it will take only one http request

  - Enable production mode in magento 2 using php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production.
  - run compilation and check if any errors using this command php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  - Check if all caches are enabled if not run this command php bin/magento cache:enable